# Trouble with new fields in Nest API data model?

Tags: json, nest-api

com mates-

I notice that `Nest` recently (late May 2015) added `hvac_state` and `wheres` to the API data model. I do not, however, see these new fields in the `JSON` output when querying my device. Was there a roll-out date for these new fields or something else I am missing? Anybody else see `hvac_state` and `wheres`?

Much thanks,
Nick

Comment: I've just checked and I also do not get them. I've found no information about a 'roll-out' date.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to change the permissions for your client in the Nest Developer site to v3.

Comment: Which really sucks because users of your application have to logout and log back in to get the new data.......